# PHP - How to change machine's DateTime only during selenium testing

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, symfony1, functional-testing

So, what I'm achieving is to prevent users to login to the site **IF** the current machine date is different from remote machine.

I've created a validation where checks and validates the machine with remote server's datetime. I've tried manual testing by changing my machine date manually and everything works fine.

The problem is, what if I want to test it by using selenium testing? I would say its just annoying to change my machine time manually everytime I want to run the test.

Here's my test function with an approach of changing default timezone (*but, it's not working*)

```
public function testLogin1()
{
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Anchorage');

  $testDate = getdate();

  var_dump(date_default_timezone_get());
  var_dump($testDate);

  $this->login('user', 'pass');

  sleep(3);
}

public function testLogin2()
{
  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Bangkok');

  $testDate = getdate();

  var_dump(date_default_timezone_get());
  var_dump($testDate);

  $this->login('user', 'pass');

  sleep(3);
}
```

Is there any specific function where I can set global php DateTime / getdate() ?

Below is my TestTime class function.

```
public static function isValid($currentDateTime) {

self::initRemoteServerDateTime();
self::initLatestUserActivityDateTime();

if (self::$remoteServerDateTime || self::$latestUserActivityDateTime) {
  $refDate = (self::$remoteServerDateTime) ? self::$remoteServerDateTime : self::$latestUserActivityDateTime;

  if ($currentDateTime->format('Y-m-d') == $refDate->format('Y-m-d')) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

And here is my action class where I call my TestTime function.

```
$currentDateTime = new DateTime();
if (!TestTime::isValid($currentDateTime)) {
  $errorMessage = 'Server\'s date and time is not set properly ['. $currentDateTime->format('j M Y H:i') .']. </br>  Please contact your system administrator.';
  throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this, array($this->getOption('username_field') => new sfValidatorError($this, $errorMessage)));
}
```

My action class is happening during the validation when user clicks the login button and submits the form.

Or, is there any different approach to do this?

Comment: Can you c/p the function you want to test?

Comment: @PierreMarichez I've added the codes for you. And for your extra information, I am using symfony framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't think there's a way to do it yet. I finally just came up with a tmp file. It's not my desired approach, but so far it works perfectly.

Here's my code before cleanup

```
protected function setUp()
{
  $my_file = '/tmp/lgnTimeValidation.tmp';
  unlink($my_file);
  $this->loadUpSession();
}

public function testLoginFromFarPast()
{
  $my_file = '/tmp/lgnTimeValidation.tmp';
  $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w+') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
  $dateTxt = "2012-12-12 12:12";
  fwrite($handle, $dateTxt);
  fseek($handle, 0);
  $fileData = fread($handle, filesize($my_file));

  $this->login('user', 'pass', 'User');

  $theText = $this->session->execute(array(
    'script' => 'return jQuery(".form_error").html();',
    'args' => array(),
    ));
  $this->assertTrue((strpos($theText, "Server's date and time is not set properly") == true));

  fclose($handle);
}

public function testLoginFromFarFuture()
{
  $my_file = '/tmp/lgnTimeValidation.tmp';
  $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w+') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
  $dateTxt = "2030-03-28 06:07";
  fwrite($handle, $dateTxt);
  fseek($handle, 0);
  $fileData = fread($handle, filesize($my_file));

  $this->login('user', 'pass', 'User');

  $theText = $this->session->execute(array(
    'script' => 'return jQuery(".form_error").html();',
    'args' => array(),
    ));
  $this->assertTrue((strpos($theText, "Server's date and time is not set properly") == true));

  fclose($handle);
}

public function testNormalLogin()
{
  $my_file = '/tmp/lgnTimeValidation.tmp';
  $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w+') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
  $dt = new DateTime();
  $dateTxt = $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  fwrite($handle, $dateTxt);
  fseek($handle, 0);
  $fileData = fread($handle, filesize($my_file));

  $this->login('user', 'pass', 'User');

  fclose($handle);
}

protected function tearDown()
{
  $my_file = '/tmp/lgnTimeValidation.tmp';
  unlink($my_file);
  $this->session->close();
}
```